Device name required for the "allowed devices" white list of an Android mobile hotspot?
I want to my laptop running Ubuntu to the white list of an Android WiFi hotspot. Doing hostnamectl returns, amongst other information, a Static hostname, an Icon name, a Machine ID, and a Boot ID. Which of these is the right one?
I got the MAC address of the wlan0 interface by doing ip addr in the terminal and added it, together with the Static hostname, to the white list, but the connection fails. Signal strength is very good and the WPA2 password is correct.
PS.: On a Windows 10 machine, you get the corresponding name by doing hostname in the command line or looking it up in Settings > System > About under "Device name".

Static hostname is the right one. You can get it as well with cat /etc/hostname without the rest, makes it easier.

@emk2203 Perfect, thanks! If you want, you could post this as an answer

Also posted on Unix.SE: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/784975/90391

The content of /etc/hostname is the hostname of the system.
Easiest to get would be with cat /etc/hostname or just calling the program hostname.
hostnamectl gives a lot of additional information (as you have seen) which can be confusing; it's better to use /etc/hostname directly.

...doing hostname does not work for me, this only prints out localhost.localdomain. Could you please double-check?

It works for me. Maybe some misconfiguration? Best to stick to cat /etc/hostname then -- this gives you the hostname without fail. I actually forgot about hostname until I saw your question, I always use cat.
